# Cannot return id specific mongo documents in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Trying to return a list of articles specific to a sectionId in angular controller. I can get back the entire list of articles using articles.query but the passed sectionId query param gets completely ignored. I tried a to abstract it to an articles service but I'm not sure how to build services correctly yet so it threw more errors. Any help / examples of how I might achieve this, preferable as a service, would be great. I am using mean.js. Thanks in advance!

Sections controller

```
angular.module('sections').controller('SectionsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Sections', 'SectionArticlesList', 'Articles',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Sections, SectionArticlesList, Articles) {
..........
        // Find existing Section
    $scope.findOne = function() {

        $scope.section = Sections.get({ 
            sectionId: $stateParams.sectionId // sections return fine
        });
        // problem starts here 
        $scope.articles = Articles.query({
            section:$stateParams.sectionId // this param is ignored
        });
        $scope.articles.$promise.then(function(data) {
           // all articles in collection returned instead of section specific
            console.log('Articles: '+ JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.articles = data;
        });
```

Articles Model

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
},
content: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
section: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Section' 
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
});
```

UPDATE:

Following up on the advice of  Kevin B and Brad Barber below, I tried adding a factory and node server route, passing the $stateParams.sectionId to the specific factory instance. I created a new route in the articles.routes.server to make sure not to have a conflict with the standard ‘/articles/:articleId’ route. Unfortunately, anything I try still either throws errors or everything in the articles collection which is the opposite of what I want to do.

section.client.controller

// Find existing Section
$scope.findOne = function() {

```
        $scope.section = Sections.get({ 
            sectionId: $stateParams.sectionId
        });

        // fails no matter what is passed to query
        $scope.articles = SectionArticlesList.query($stateParams.sectionId);
        //$scope.SectionArticlesList.query($stateParams.sectionId);
        //$scope.articles = SectionArticlesList.query({sectionId});

        $scope.articles.$promise.then(function(data) {
            // still only ever returns full list of articles
            console.log('Length of articles: '+ JSON.stringify(data.length));
            $scope.articles = data;
        });
```

….

articles.client.services

```
angular.module('articles').factory('SectionArticlesList', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles/:articleSectionId', {
        articleSectionId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
]);
```

articles.server.routes

```
// Custom route
app.route('/articles/:articleSectionId')
    .get(articles.listBySectionID);
// Custom binding
app.param('articleSectionId', articles.listBySectionID);
```

articles.server.controller

The server side controller function never appears to get called because neither of the console.logs show up.

```
exports.listBySectionID = function(req, res, id) {
console.log('listBySection Called....'); // this is never printed
// have tried passing - id, sectionId and {section:id}
Article.find( {section:id} ).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, articles) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('listBySection err triggered...'); // this neither
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.json(articles);
    }
});
};
```

I think I have tried everything I can think of to pass the sectionId correctly but nothing has worked yet. The latest error in the console is the 404 below.Interestingly the sectionId IS getting through but as if it is looking for one single resource such as a single blog post.

```
GET /sectionArticles?sectionId=555bfaf29a005c30cbfe6931 404
```

I don't quite understand how the default mean.js `/articles` route and it's corresponding list function works but duplicating a similar structure and passing an id as a param to the query to retrieve only specific results doesn't.

Would really like to understand how this should be wired up. If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong I’d appreciate it!

Comment: I'd suspect the model or api route before i suspect the angular in this case.

Comment: @kevin B. Thanks for response. There isn't a route involved per se. The Articles model is injected as a dependency of the Sections controller. Should that not give direct access to the model api? I included the Articles schema just to show how the section is defined, in case that's where I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I mean, on your server(node.js) you have a route somewhere that is handling api requests to query the articles model. that's what i was referring to.

Comment: It looks like you're using the default Mean.js template - the express implementation of the api doesn't check query parameters by default. Have you updated the implementation to query by section? Here's where you'd need to make the change: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/controllers/articles.server.controller.js#L75

Comment: Thanks again guys for your help. I posted an update above with a few things I tired based on those suggestions. Still having problems though.